# How can I only show the numbers on a newly calculated df column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issue where calculated results in "Price Tier Index" column are showing up as "object" and not as an int (see code and screenshot below).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import io
from IPython.display import display
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()    

#this is a variable to be used in the new Price Tier Index column  
men_bw_avg_eq_price = 0.28

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded["Men BW - competitive price tier analysis - REPULLED.csv"]))
df= df.fillna(0)

price_index = []
total_rows = len(df['Products']) 
for i in range(total_rows): 
      pi_value = (df.loc[i, ['Avg EQ Price']]/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100  
      price_index.append(pi_value)

df['Price Tier Index'] = price_index
df[['Brand', 'Gender', 'Subcategory']] = df.Products.str.split("|", expand=True)
df_new = df[['Brand', 'Price Tier Index']]
display(df_new)
```

[screenshot of the current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql2a9.png)

[screenshot of what I'm looking to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IYRv.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: it may suggest that you forgot `()` to get strings . or you get `type of data` instead of `data`

Comment: how about `price_index = (df['Avg EQ Price']/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100` without `for`-loop?

Comment: maybe all problem is that you run it in loop and you may create `list of dataframes` instead of `list od values` and later it convert it to strings with `Avg EQ Price` and with `dtype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problem is because you create `list of dataframes` instead of `list of values`

You need `.values[0]` or `.to_list()[0]` to convert data to list and get first value

```
first_value = df.loc[i, ['Avg EQ Price']].values[0]
pi_value = (first_value/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100
```

```
first_value = df.loc[i, ['Avg EQ Price']].to_list()[0]
pi_value = (first_value/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100
```

But you can calculate it without `for`-loop

```
df['Price Tier Index'] = (df['Avg EQ Price']/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100
```

---

Minimal working example with some data

```
import pandas as pd

#this is a variable to be used in the new Price Tier Index column  
men_bw_avg_eq_price = 0.28

data = {
    'Products': ['A|B|C','D|E|F','G|H|I'], 
    'Avg EQ Price': [4,5,6], 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded["Men BW - competitive price tier analysis - REPULLED.csv"]))
df = df.fillna(0)

#price_index = []
#total_rows = len(df['Products'])
#for i in range(total_rows): 
#      #first_value = df.loc[i, ['Avg EQ Price']].values[0]
#      first_value = df.loc[i, ['Avg EQ Price']].to_list()[0]
#      pi_value = (first_value/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100  
#      price_index.append(pi_value)

price_index = (df['Avg EQ Price']/men_bw_avg_eq_price) * 100  

df['Price Tier Index'] = price_index
df[['Brand', 'Gender', 'Subcategory']] = df.Products.str.split("|", expand=True)
df_new = df[['Brand', 'Price Tier Index']]

print(df_new)
```

Result:

```
  Brand  Price Tier Index
0     A       1428.571429
1     D       1785.714286
2     G       2142.857143
```